# Symbol resolution in C

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm learning symbol resolution in linking:

"Rule 2: given a strong symbol and multi weak symbols, choose the strong one."
(from the book CSAPP)

I tried the following example, but got multiple definition error. It seems not following the Rule2 above.

strong.c

```
int x = 20;
```

weak.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;

int main() {
    printf("%c\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc -c strong.c
$ gcc -c weak.c

$ gcc weak.o strong.o
/usr/bin/ld: strong.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `x'; weak.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
$ nm strong.o
0000000000000000 D x
$ nm weak.o
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
0000000000000000 B x
```

I used `nm` to check the symbols: `x` in `weak.o` is B(uninitialized global, weak symbol); `x` in `strong.o` is D(initialized global, strong symbol).

Comment: You call it `weak.c`, but nowhere do you make anything weak.

Comment: GCC’s default treatment of tentative definitions changed in version 10. Use `-fcommon` to get the old behavior.

Comment: Or, rather, don't use `-fcommon` because it is not the official behaviour required by the C standard, though many compilers recognize it.